# Custom Customer attribute not being created in database magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, customer-attribute, entities

I am trying to add a new **attribute** called '**customer_type**' to **Customer** Entity. Customer module has already been registered before.

- I have added the lines of code to
  /Magento/vendor/magento/module-customer/Setup/UpgradeData.php .
- I have run 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade'

What am i doing wrong here? Please guide me through the process

```
<?php


namespace Magento\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
/**
 * Customer setup factory
 *
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
protected $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var IndexerRegistry
 */
protected $indexerRegistry;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
 */
protected $eavConfig;

/**
 * @var AllowedCountries
 */
private $allowedCountriesReader;

/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
private $storeManager;

/**
 * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(
        Customer::ENTITY,
        'customer_type',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Type',
            'input' => 'hidden',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'visible' => false,
            'system' => true,
        ]
    );

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.6', '<')) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroSix($customerSetup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroOne($customerSetup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2') < 0) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroTwo($customerSetup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.3', '<')) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroThree($customerSetup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.4', '<')) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroFour($customerSetup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.5', '<')) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroFive($customerSetup, $setup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.6', '<')) {
        $setup->getConnection()->delete(
            $setup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
            ['form_code = ?' => 'checkout_register']
        );
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.7', '<')) {
        $this->upgradeVersionTwoZeroSeven($customerSetup);
        $this->upgradeCustomerPasswordResetlinkExpirationPeriodConfig($setup);
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.9', '<')) {
        $setup->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

        try {
            $this->migrateStoresAllowedCountriesToWebsite($setup);
            $setup->getConnection()->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $setup->getConnection()->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    $indexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Customer::CUSTOMER_GRID_INDEXER_ID);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
    $this->eavConfig->clear();
    $setup->endSetup();
}
/* REST OF THE CODE */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Trying to work in vendor file that's wrong practice for Magento, please follow bellow steps to create customer attribute

Create New module inside app/code
 Create New Folder => Test (Vendor)
 Inside Test Folder Create "CustomAttribute"

> **1) Test/CustomAttribute/registration.php**

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_CustomAttribute',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **2) Test/CustomAttribute/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_CustomAttribute" setup_version="0.1.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> **3) Test/CustomAttribute/SetupInstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\CustomAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'customer_type',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_type')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Now Run below command to install module

```
Run command: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> Refernce link :
>
> https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-customer-custom-attribute-in-magento-2-0/

Comment: i am working in vendor just for convenience purpose now, is there any restriction that makes it impossible to create a new attribute in vendor folder?

Comment: but its not peroper way , you to update version of customer module if you want worked with vendor files , it's not advisable to worked direct in vendor files , just used above code for same you will ahicheve ur goal.